# ANSI X9.31 PRNG successor

Tags: random

I want to know if there is a successor for X9.31 (AES) based generators in crypto++ library, since the X9.31 cannot be used after December 2015 (NIST SP800-131A)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ANSI X9.31 generator successor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65208728/ansi-x9-31-generator-successor)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an approved CSPRNG, then you want either the HMAC DRBG or the Hash DRBG, both of which are approved by NIST and are in Crypto++.  You will want to seed it using the OS CSPRNG, which is also available in Crypto++.

The HMAC DRBG has been found to be slightly more likely to resist attacks, but the Hash DRBG is going to be faster in a typical implementation.  There are no known practical attacks on either when used correctly.

If you don't have a strong need for compliance, I'd go with just using the OS PRNG and stick with that.  The OS PRNG is going to be robust and secure and even if you picked another algorithm, you'd still need to seed with it anyway.

If you do need to pick an approved algorithm for compliance reasons but don't otherwise have a strong preference, use an HMAC DRBG with SHA-512, seeded from the OS RNG, which provides the best possible security and the best possible performance for an HMAC DRBG on 64-bit systems.

Comment: I want to generate a random key for CMAC algorithm. I search for a paper comparing the different PRNG in Crypto++ library to justify my choice.

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide some suggestions.  I think if you pick either of those options, they'll be entirely defensible and nobody will argue about them at all.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response. All your suggestions are good but i would like to make a decision based on a scientific paper. I want to combine "security", "speed" and "lightness" because i use CMAC to secure a routing protocol in a MANET.